# ValueError: max_features=0, neither a positive integer nor None when using chunksize to increase speed

Tags: python, pandas

As the title states, I am trying to use counter vectorizer to calculate the unique words and further process my data. My dataset has 600k rows (750MB) of data and the memory is not enough, thus I decided to use the chunksize to see if I can minimize the time needed. Then the error rises
Here is what I did, I cannot tell which part caused the problem:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    nRowsRead = 2000  # specify 'None' if want to read whole file
    chunksize = 100
    df1 = pd.read_csv('Cleaned_Depression_Vs_Suicide.csv', delimiter=',',
                      nrows=nRowsRead, usecols=[1, 2, 7], chunksize=chunksize)
    df1.dataframeName = 'Cleaned_Depression_Vs_Suicide.csv'
    for chunk in df1:
        chunk.dropna(axis=0, how='any', inplace=True)
        chunk['cleaned_text'] = ''
        chunk.to_csv("sample.csv", index=False)
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    stopwords = spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS
    stopwords.add("-PRON-")

    for chunk in df1:
        result1 = preprocessing(chunk['Title'])
        result2 = preprocessing(chunk['Body'])
        chunk['cleaned_text'] = result1 + ' ' + result2
        print(chunk['cleaned_text'])
        chunk.dropna(axis=0, how='any', inplace=True)
        chunk.to_csv('sample.csv', index=False)

    unique_words = {}
    for text in df1:
        for k in text['cleaned_text']:
            for word in k.split():
                if word not in unique_words.keys():
                    unique_words[word] = 1
                else:
                    unique_words[word] += 1

    unique_words = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(unique_words,orient="index",columns=["frequency"])
    unique_words.sort_values(by=["frequency"], inplace=True, ascending=False)

    nX, nY = unique_words.shape
    unique_words.head(n=nX)

    unique_words = unique_words[unique_words['frequency'] >= 10]
    df2 = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
    df2.dropna(axis=0, how='any', inplace=True)
    # Used the sklearn CountVectorizer function instead for computational efficiency
    # Function was used to transform all the unique words into number of appearance.
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    bag_of_words = CountVectorizer(max_features=unique_words.shape[0], dtype='uint8').fit_transform(
        df2["cleaned_text"])
    Subreddit = {'depression': 0, 'SuicideWatch': 1, np.nan: 0}
    df2.Subreddit = [Subreddit[item] for item in df2.Subreddit]
    df2.to_csv('sample.csv', index=False)

    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    X = bag_of_words
    y = df2['Subreddit']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=123)
```

Here is how the preprocessing looks like, I implemented this the same as an online blog:

```
def preprocessing(s):
  
    # Split
    # We also need to remove the null / nan value in the dataset.
    s = s.split()

    # Lowercase
    s = [word.lower() for word in s]

    # Remove non-letters
    s = [re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z]', '', word) for word in s]

    # Remove non-letters
    s = [re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', word) for word in s]

    # spaCy conversion for lemmatization
    s = " ".join(s)
    s = nlp(s)

    # Lemmatization
    lemmas = [token.lemma_ for token in s]

    cleaned_lemmas = [word for word in lemmas if not word in stopwords]

    cleaned_lemmas = " ".join(cleaned_lemmas)

    return cleaned_lemmas
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\SVMPractice\h.py", line 181, in <module>
    bag_of_words = CountVectorizer(max_features=unique_words.shape[0], dtype='uint8').fit_transform(
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\SVMPractice\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\SVMPractice\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1033, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: max_features=0, neither a positive integer nor None
```

This is my first time doing something like this to practice and everything works fine before I add the chunksize parameter, I believe there is something I am missing, any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: `max_features=unique_words.shape[0]` -> If unique_words is empty (which may happen, if one of the splits is empty) max_features is 0 and you get the error. Put a test on the shape of unique_words before calling CountVectorizer.

Comment: @GPhilo Hi, so to put a test, if there is an empty case, what should I do? Ignore that split and skip to the next? Also, before I use the chunksize, this part works fine and none of the split is empty, so I am wondering which part above caused the problem.